# Расположить пункты меню симметрично слева и справа?

Tags: html, css, html5

Всем привет. Подскажите как половину пунктов меню расположить с левого края, а оставшуюся часть симметрично с правого? Количество пунктов может меняться, но всегда будет оставаться четным.

```css
    .navigation > ul > li {
      float: left;
    }
    .navigation > ul > li > a {
      padding: 20px 30px;
    }
#navigation {
 overflow: hidden;
}
#navigation .menu-item:nth-child(0+n/n) {
 float:left;
}
#navigation .menu-item:nth-child(1+n/2) {
 float:right;
}
```

```html
<nav id="navigation" class="navigation">
  <ul>
    <li id="menu-item-2953" class="menu-item"><a href="#">Главная</a>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-2953" class="menu-item"><a href="#">О компании</a>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-2952" class="menu-item"><a href="#">Каталог</a>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-2951" class="menu-item"><a href="#">Новости</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Математику(деление) к сожалению css не воспринимает..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Интересное решение найденное на зарубежном [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15466898/selecting-half-the-elements-with-nth-child)

```css
ul {
    list-style: none;
    width: 600px;
}
li {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}

li:first-child:last-child,
li:nth-child(n+1):nth-last-child(-n+2),
li:nth-child(n+3):nth-last-child(-n+4),
li:nth-child(n+5):nth-last-child(-n+6),
li:nth-child(n+7):nth-last-child(-n+8){
    float: right;    
}
```

```html
<nav id="navigation" class="navigation">
  <ul>
    <li id="menu-item-2953" class="menu-item"><a href="#">Главная</a>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-2953" class="menu-item"><a href="#">О компании</a>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-2952" class="menu-item"><a href="#">Каталог</a>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-2951" class="menu-item"><a href="#">Новости</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Вау, супер! благодарю, то что надо!

Answer (score 1):

Вот ответ на ваш вопрос. nth-child с параметром even и odd обрабатывают четные и нечетные элементы соответственно.

```css
.navigation > ul > li:nth-child(odd) {
  float: left;
}

.navigation > ul > li:nth-child(even) {
  float: right;
}
.navigation > ul > li > a {
  padding: 20px 30px;
}
```

```html
<nav id="navigation" class="navigation">
  <ul>
    <li id="menu-item-2953" class="menu-item"><a href="#">О компании</a>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-2953" class="menu-item"><a href="#">О компании</a>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-2952" class="menu-item"><a href="#">Каталог</a>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-2951" class="menu-item"><a href="#">Новости</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ, но задание немного не то - у вас четные пункты разбежались в 1 сторону, а нечетные в другую, а мне же важна последовательность: т.е. с первой половины 1,2,3,4,5 пункты, а со второй 6,7,8,9,10. мысль понятна?

Comment: Понял. На CSS это можно реализовать практический чуть ли не прописывая для каждого пункта условие с nth-child. Может имеет смысл сразу разнести пункты меню так, что бы порядок был как надо?

Comment: надо дать пользователю возможность создавать пункты самому не разнося и не заморачиваясь над этим.
жду, что может кто додумается как это реализовать более хитрым способом - моя надежда на знание css простейшего деления не оправдалась..

Answer (score 1):

[За основу взял код предыдущего ответа](http://output.jsbin.com/cawutoyodu)

```css
nav {
  width: 350px;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  border-top: none;
  border-bottom: none;
}
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0 20px;
}
ul:after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: block;
}
li:nth-child(odd) {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: left;
}
li:nth-child(even) {
  float: right;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: right;
}
li:nth-child(odd) a {
  float: left;
}
li:nth-child(even) a {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<nav id="navigation" class="navigation">
  <ul>
    <li id="menu-item-2953" class="menu-item"><a href="#">Главная</a>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-2953" class="menu-item"><a href="#">О компании</a>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-2952" class="menu-item"><a href="#">Каталог</a>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-2951" class="menu-item"><a href="#">Новости</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ, но я имел ввиду расположить что-то вроде этого (т.е. 1ые 2 пункта главная и о компании слева, а каталог и новости справа):
http://jsfiddle.net/m4u7zmbw/1/
но, конечно же не используя классы `left` и `right` в `html`

Comment: @Вася, ну тогда прописывайте для каждого `nth-child`, слева используя код для `odd`, справа для `even`

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю, правильно ли я понял задачу. Но как вам такой вариант: меню позиционируем абсолютно, делаем его двухколоночным. Расстояние между колонками - это ширина контента. Контент сдвигаем на ширину левого меню.

Но это `CSS3`.

```css
#content {
  width: 300px;
  text-align: justify;
  margin: 0 200px;
}
#navigation {
  width: 700px;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#navigation ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  -moz-column-count: 2; /* Для Firefox */
  -moz-column-gap: 300px;
  -webkit-column-count: 2; /* Для Safari и Chrome */
  -webkit-column-gap: 300px;
  column-count: 2;
  column-gap: 300px;
}
#navigation ul > li {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<nav id="navigation" class="navigation">
  <ul>
    <li id="menu-item-2953" class="menu-item"><a href="#">Главная</a>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-2953" class="menu-item"><a href="#">О компании</a>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-2952" class="menu-item"><a href="#">Каталог</a>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-2951" class="menu-item"><a href="#">Новости</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<div id='content'>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi feugiat, quam a vulputate tempus, dolor justo accumsan massa, at molestie nibh leo sed dolor. Fusce condimentum neque nibh, at semper mauris rhoncus sed.
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо за старания, но нет. вверху уже Vitaliy Shevchenko правильно понял задачу и дал правильный ответ)

Comment: @Вася жаль, мне даже самому понравилась идея. )